# Is there a Gson @DeserializedName equivalent to the @SerializedName annotation?

Tags: java, serialization, gson, deserialization

I'm able to set the `@SerializedName` to `this_field` so when I use the `toJson()` function it'll use it properly. However when I'm trying to read it in via `fromJson()` function it'll try to use `thisField`.

Normally I'd create a serializer like the one below; however is there something built in that will handle this or is the only way to make a custom deserializer for each class?

A class

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class A {
    @SerializedName("this_field")
    private Integer thisField;
}
```

ADeserializer class

```
public class ADeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<A> {
    @Override
    public Additional deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject obj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        return A.builder()
                .thisField(obj.get("this_field").isJsonNull() ? null : obj.get("this_field").getAsJsonObject)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

> public abstract String[] alternate Returns: the alternative names of
> the field when it is deserialized

so you can use

```
@SerializedName(value="this_field", alternate={"thisField"}) 
private Integer thisField;
```

This would lead into `this_field` being used during serialization.

During deserialization it would be used `this_field` if it is available and if not it will use `thisField` if this becomes available.